# Magento 2: Static images returns 404 after refresh

Tags: magento2, 404

This is driving me crazy.

I added a couple of images to my theme. They are on my `theme_name/web/images` folder.

The images are returning a 404.

I delete the folder `pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme_name/en_US` and on the first access they load. As soon as I try to load the images again they return **404** again.
The images are in the correct path.

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Permissions?

Comment: Which code have you written to call images?

Comment: <?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/selos/filename.svg'); ?>
Any better solution?

Comment: Can you please share your image URL which you are getting by above code?

Comment: domain/pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme_name/en_US/images/selos/filename.svg
I've tried with "Sign Static Files" set to yes and no. Both return the same result. 
Also tried replacing every svg file with png's. Nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after days of looking into this problem I realised it had nothing to do with magento at all.
Our designer was uploading the images trough Mega (client), and for some reason after I downloaded the images that problem occurred. 
After sending me the same images another the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case with facebook logo (svg). I assume the logo is in a compressed format. To fix the 404, I made a copy of the logo with inskape and replace the original image with the new file. After this process the image is four time bigger (600b for 2.2kb).

Answer (score 0):

**Call Media Images in PHTML Files**

```
<img src="<?php echo $mediaUrl.'wysiwyg/demo.jpg'; ?>" />
```

**Call Web Images in PHTML File**

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/demo.png'); ?>" />
```

**Call Web Images in Static block and CMS page**

```
<img src="{{view url="images/demo.jpg"}}" />
```

**Call Media Images in Static block and CMS page**

```
<img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/demo.png'}}; ?>" />
```